# Brightway2 - Importing ecospold1 processes exported from openLCA

Tags: brightway

I have an ecospold1 dataset extracted from openLCA and I would like to import it into Brightway2.
Using the SingleOutputEcospold1Importer should read the ecospold files but apparently something is wrong in the file schema.

Given the possible export formats of openLCA and the possible import formats of Brightway2, ecospold1 seems to be the only common format. If there is any other way to do it, I would be happy to try.

**Code:**

```
import brightway2 as bw

bw.projects.set_current('importing_ecospold1')
bw.bw2setup()

fp = "path/to/EcoSpold01"
importer = bw.SingleOutputEcospold1Importer(fp, 'database_name', use_mp=False)
```

**Output**

```
File ~\miniconda3\envs\playing_with_brightway\lib\site-packages\bw2io\extractors\ecospold1.py:132, in Ecospold1DataExtractor.process_dataset(cls, dataset, filename, db_name)
    109 @classmethod
    110 def process_dataset(cls, dataset, filename, db_name):
    111     ref_func = dataset.metaInformation.processInformation.referenceFunction
    112     comments = [
    113         ref_func.get("generalComment"),
    114         ref_func.get("includedProcesses"),
    115         (
    116             "Location: ",
    117             dataset.metaInformation.processInformation.geography.get("text"),
    118         ),
    119         (
    120             "Technology: ",
    121             dataset.metaInformation.processInformation.technology.get("text"),
    122         ),
    123         (
    124             "Time period: ",
    125             getattr2(dataset.metaInformation.processInformation, "timePeriod").get(
    126                 "text"
    127             ),
    128         ),
    129         (
    130             "Production volume: ",
    131             getattr2(
--> 132                 dataset.metaInformation.modellingAndValidation, "representativeness"
    133             ).get("productionVolume"),
    134         ),
    135         (
    136             "Sampling: ",
    137             getattr2(
    138                 dataset.metaInformation.modellingAndValidation, "representativeness"
    139             ).get("samplingProcedure"),
    140         ),
    141         (
    142             "Extrapolations: ",
    143             getattr2(
    144                 dataset.metaInformation.modellingAndValidation, "representativeness"
    145             ).get("extrapolations"),
    146         ),
    147         (
    148             "Uncertainty: ",
    149             getattr2(
    150                 dataset.metaInformation.modellingAndValidation, "representativeness"
    151             ).get("uncertaintyAdjustments"),
    152         ),
    153     ]
    155     def get_authors():
    156         ai = dataset.metaInformation.administrativeInformation

File src/lxml/objectify.pyx:234, in lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement.__getattr__()

File src/lxml/objectify.pyx:453, in lxml.objectify._lookupChildOrRaise()

AttributeError: no such child: {http://www.EcoInvent.org/EcoSpold01}modellingAndValidation
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be hard to fix in the SO format - if your data is not confidential, please file a new [brightway2-io issue](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues/new) with some sample data. If your data is confidential, you will need to make up an example project and export that, we need to XML files to fix this.

Comment: I just did in https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/issues/126